# How can I remove an element of array without using list or collection methods

Tags: java, arrays

I should build a class like an array class and I should consider a remove method that is able to remove an element by index and by value.

```
public void delet(int index) {
    int shouldBeDelet=Containor[index];
    Containor copy=new Containor();
    int numberOfReapeat=0;
    rear=0;
    for (int i=0 ;i<Containor.length;i++){
        if (Containor[i]!=shouldBeDelet){
            copy.add(Containor[i]);
        }
        else numberOfReapeat++;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<copy.size()-numberOfReapeat-1;i++){
        Containor[i]=copy.get(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to delete an item from an array, you don't need to make a copy.  You just need to shift the remaining elements towards the start of the array.  For example, if you want to delete the element at index 2 out of an array of 5 elements, then you would effectively run array[2] = array[3], and array[3] = array[4].  Then you are stuck with the problem of what to do with array[4].  You might want to copy a subset of the array to a smaller array, or you can keep track of your array length internally, or you could set it to null... there are a few options.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove an object from an array without creating a new array, unless you permit unused array entries. An array has a fix length. Removing one entry of an array, however, would have to change this length or leave one entry empty.

the first approach would be, to just clear the entry which shall be removed:

```
public void remove(int indexToRemove){
  this.array[indexToRemove] = null;
}
```

I would not recommend this solution, since you practically do not remove any element from the array, you just override it with `null`;

The second approach is to remove the entry and shift every following element to the left (lower index). However, this just moves the null element to the end of the list.

```
public void remove(int indexToRemove){
  for (int i = indexToRemove+1; i < this.array.length; i++) {
    this.array[i-1] = this.array[i];
  }

  this.array[this.array.length] = null;
}
```

A much better approach would be to create a new array containing the n-1 entries of the old array by adding each entry of the old array to the new array except the one to remove:

```
public void remove(int indexToRemove){
  YourClass[] newArray = new YourClass[this.array.length-1];

  int newArrayIndex = 0;
  for (int oldArrayIndex = 0; oldArrayIndex < this.array.length; oldArrayIndex++) {
    if (oldArrayIndex != indexToRemove) {
      newArray[newArrayIndex] = this.array[oldArrayIndex];
      newArrayIndex++;
    }
  }

 this.array = newArray;
}
```